# How To create this custom shape in react konva

Tags: reactjs, react-konva, konva, konvajs-reactjs

Hi I am new to react konva and trying to make a custom shape for my project
I wanted to create the yellow element which is basically a trapezium with curved sides and should fit inside the red ring as shown in the image. Any help is much appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Konva.Ring](https://konvajs.org/docs/shapes/Ring.html) and [Konva.Arc](https://konvajs.org/docs/shapes/Arc.html) shapes for that.

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Stage, Layer, Arc, Ring } from "react-konva";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>
      <Layer>
        <Ring
          x={200}
          y={200}
          innerRadius={40}
          outerRadius={70}
          fill="red"
          stroke="black"
        />
        <Arc
          x={200}
          y={200}
          innerRadius={40}
          outerRadius={70}
          angle={60}
          rotation={-120}
          fill="yellow"
          stroke="black"
        />
      </Layer>
    </Stage>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-arc-demo-yhkoh